# Ember nested views

Tags: ember.js

Question about the 'ember way' of handling nested views for this case.  Using ember-cli -- I have a resource named 'customers'.   The view hierarchy is:

```
customers
+- customers.index
+- customers.show
```

I would like to place a banner at the customers level, but have a portion of it's contents specified at the .index or .show level.

So I add a property to the customers controller and show that in a customers template.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  headingText: 'initial'
}
```

template

```
<h3>{{ headingText }}</h3>
{{ outlet }}
```

The child controllers can see the value, but upon changing it -- the view does not change (prototype -vs- inheritance?)

In order to change the headingText from a child controller, I need to do this in each child:

```
needs: "customers",
headingText: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.customers.headingText")
```

Is this the 'ember way'?   Seems like there should be an easier way to bubble up information without the boilerplate (method on customers controller or something).

Assuming the header text will contain information from a resolved model, where is the best place to set it?  In the route?  aftermodel?

Thanks

Comment: You can consider making the `headingText` a named outlet. Then, in the child routes' `renderTemplate` method, add a call to `this.render` to render the relevant header into the named outlet. The alternative, of course, is just to replicate the `h3` in each of the child route templates.

Comment: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ :)

Comment: Named outlets is an option, but it feels like using a hammer on a tack here.

This originally was supposed to be a quick question, and I kept on typing.   Is there a quick way to single fileify an ember-cli podified mini-app?

Answer (score 0):

In the child routes, you might consider using the `setupController` hook to modify the properties of the parent route.

[Ember API docs for setupController](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController)

Within `setupController`, you can get and set properties on a route other than the one directly associated with the current route using this syntax:

In a child route:

```
setupController(controller, model) {
    this.controllerFor('customers').set('headingText', 'My awesome new header for the child route.');
}
```

Controllers are singletons, and persist their state, so you may need to explicitly set the `headingText` property to the correct value in each relevant route file.

[Here's more info on the `controllerFor` route property.](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_controllerFor)